# Кто знает что это такое simplestreams.us?

Tags: ip

С любого компа этот адрес пингуется как 127.0.0.1
http://2ip.ru показывает так же 127.0.0.1
Если вбить через яндекс - есть такой сайт)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто некий Johnny Direa из Гамбурга, хозяин этого домена, захотел чтоб символьное имя соответствовало адресу 127.0.0.1 , что в этом удивительного? Можете сами у него спросить зачем он это сделал, например, по e-mail'у: pedalisimo@yahoo.com

Comment: Таки да)) вот чудак))

Comment: Между прочим на этот сайт ссылается некая прога по трансляции видео.... в результате шлюз кидает кучу ошибок в логи... имеем нереальный рост лог файла(